# Getting Field value for a given coordinate out of ESRI Shapefile using GDAL/OGR

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, c++

I have a bunch of ESRI shapefiles that contain Land Cover data across Canada (provided by [Geobase](http://geobase.ca/)). I need to query the files and obtain the value of a certain field (called COVTYPE) in a given location specified either by lat/lon or UTM coordinates. I can open a file in Quantum GIS and find the needed values manually, but this process needs to be done automatically for a large number of values so I'm using C++ and GDAL.

I'm very new to the whole GIS area and I'm just starting to learn GDAL. So far I've learned how to loop over layers, features, fields etc, but I can't figure out how to relate coordinates to features. I went through the official GDAL/OGR tutorials, but I'm still stuck. Any pointers would be appreciated!

**Update:**
Just to clarify. My input data would be coordinates (lat/lon or UTM). So the way I imagine this should work is:

1. I find which feature the given point is located within
2. read the field value in that feature

I know how to do step 2, but I'm stuck at step 1.

**Final solution**
Technically, the update to Ragi's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30666/getting-field-value-for-a-given-coordinate-out-of-esri-shapefile-using-gdal-ogr/30672#30672) comes very close to what I need to do, but I'll post here a quick summary of how I ended up using it. My way is easier for constructing a point geometry object.

So leaving all the boilerplate code out, the essential part is:

```
OGRPoint* point = new OGRPoint(some_longitude, some_latitude);
layer->SetSpatialFilter(point); //getting only the feature intercepting the point
OGRFeature* feature = layer->GetNextFeature();
int value = feature->GetFieldAsInteger(0); //getting the value - DONE!
//in my case it's 1st field, hence the 0th index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [OGR API Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html) you will find this piece of code which does something very close to what you want:

```
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"

int main()
{
    OGRRegisterAll();

    OGRDataSource       *poDS;

    poDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open( "point.shp", FALSE );
    if( poDS == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Open failed.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    OGRLayer  *poLayer;

    poLayer = poDS->GetLayerByName( "point" );

    OGRFeature *poFeature;

    poLayer->ResetReading();
    while( (poFeature = poLayer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL )
    {
        OGRFeatureDefn *poFDefn = poLayer->GetLayerDefn();
        int iField;

        for( iField = 0; iField < poFDefn->GetFieldCount(); iField++ )
        {
            OGRFieldDefn *poFieldDefn = poFDefn->GetFieldDefn( iField );

            if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTInteger )
                printf( "%d,", poFeature->GetFieldAsInteger( iField ) );
            else if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTReal )
                printf( "%.3f,", poFeature->GetFieldAsDouble(iField) );
            else if( poFieldDefn->GetType() == OFTString )
                printf( "%s,", poFeature->GetFieldAsString(iField) );
            else
                printf( "%s,", poFeature->GetFieldAsString(iField) );
        }

        OGRGeometry *poGeometry;

        poGeometry = poFeature->GetGeometryRef();
        if( poGeometry != NULL 
            && wkbFlatten(poGeometry->getGeometryType()) == wkbPoint )
        {
            OGRPoint *poPoint = (OGRPoint *) poGeometry;

            printf( "%.3f,%3.f\n", poPoint->getX(), poPoint->getY() );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "no point geometry\n" );
        }       
        OGRFeature::DestroyFeature( poFeature );
    }

    OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource( poDS );
}
```

The relevant lines are

```
poFeature->GetFieldAsInteger( iField )
poFeature->GetFieldAsDouble(iField)
poFeature->GetFieldAsString(iField)
```

**Update:** Based on the comments below, it sounds like what you need is a spatial query. To do a spatial query, all you need is to create a geometry object and set it before the loop. The easiest way I can think of creating your query geometry is to simply use one of the methods in [OGRGeometryFactory](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometryFactory.html) (like [OGRGeometryFactory::ConstructFromWKT](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometryFactory.html#a9418f71bcfb1e334173882c38d89d070)) to the a OGRGeometry object, then you pass that object to [OGRLayer::SetSpatialFilter](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#a0b4ab45cf97cbc470f0d60474d3e4169).

There are plenty of examples in the [OGR test suite](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/). Nevertheless, the ones that are easier to understand (i.e. that don't have much of test harness cruft) are the [python tests](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_basic_test.py). I would start with those. The API is very symmetrical to the C++ one, so translating from one to the other should be very easy.

Comment: Yes, I've gotten that far - I know how to get the required field values for a certain feature in a certain layer (there is actually just 1 layer in these files). But how do I know which feature I need to read?

Comment: Are you asking how to figure out which point intersects a particular polygon? You can do that with a Spatial Query.  Before you start looping, you set a spatial filter http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#a0b4ab45cf97cbc470f0d60474d3e4169

Comment: Yes, I think it sounds like what I need to do. I'll give it a try and see where it leads me. Do you happen to have any code examples for spatial queries?

Comment: Updated the answer above

Answer (score 3):

To find which feature the coordinate is near, you first need to build an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) index of bounding boxes or envelope of each feature. A popular library for this is [libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.com/).

Secondly, you would then need to know for each of the matched features from your R-tree, which ones match. GDAL/OGR does have some operations based on GEOS to see if the geometry "contains" the point of interest, and you can extract the field info. See the [OGRGeometry Class Reference](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometry.html) for `Contains`, `Touches`, `Within`, etc. that can perform the geometry relation operator.

---

Personally I wouldn't do any of the above, because it would take me too long to figure out the coding, and I know there are faster ways. (I would [loading all shapefiles in a PostGIS database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7803/bulk-load-multiple-shapefiles-into-postgis/7806#7806), then query the locations using SQL.) However, it is understandable if this GIS functionality needs to be embedded in an existing project without adding more complicated dependencies, such as a database server.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I have to do it in C++ only - adding a database to this is not an option at this point. It probably would be easier if I had all the data in a DB, but right now I have a bunch of separate files and it's likely to stay that way in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if/how you can do this in GDAL (or OGR technically, for vectors). However, you most certainly can do it easily in QGIS. First, create a point shapefile from your locations (if it's not already). Then you want to do a "Join Attributes By Location" available under the Vector > Data Management Tools Menu.

Comment: Yes, I can do it in QGis, but I have to automate the process. It has to be done "in background".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't realize it had to be a 'background' job. In that case, I second Mike Toews PostGIS suggestion.